# Efficiently fetching thumbnails of local files in Electron app

Tags: typescript, electron, thumbnails, desktop-application

First off, please excuse my ignorance on the subject of Electron and desktop apps in general. I'm an Android developer, but our team is working on an Electron app for PC/Mac. The app scans your computer for files and backs them up, all while showing thumbnails for each file. We're having problems loading these thumbnails quickly, so the results are slow and low-resolution. We're also being forced to encode the thumbnails as Base64 strings in order to pass them from the back end to the front end of the code. Is there a better way to do this for Electron apps?

Also, on Android, we have an excellent image loading library called Glide that automatically solves many of the complexities of this problem. Is there some similar library that we could employ in Electron? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
const { app } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const desktopPath = app.getPath('desktop')
console.log(desktopPath)
let filePaths = fs.readdirSync(desktopPath)
for (let filePath of filePaths) {
    app.getFileIcon(filePath).then((fileIcon) => {
        fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + `/images/img-${filePath}.png`, fileIcon.toPNG())
    })
}
```

Electron has its own [`app`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app) module that allows you to get a path like Desktop or Documents, and it can also get file icons and output them in JPEG or PNG.

I've noticed your question has the `typescript` tag, however I do not work in TypeScript so you will need to convert it but hopefully the code is similar.

**Edit**:

Resize it by changing `fileIcon.toPNG()` with this:

```
fileIcon.resize({
            height: 256,
            width: 256,
            quality: 100
        }).toPNG()
```

Comment: I appreciate the reply. The problem with `getFileIcon()` is that it returns 32x32 icons, but we need much larger images. We're also looking at `nativeImage.createThumbnailFromPath()`, but we still need a way to pass these images to the UI layer. The current thought is to use an internal HTTP server for this.

Comment: Hey! Thanks, I edited the post to include a way to resize it but it's not the best. Tell me if that works a little better. As for your `nativeImage.createThumbnailFromPath()`, I might have a look at that and try to help.

Comment: If you used `createThumbnailFromPath()`, it'd end up trying to render the text for text files like `.js`, `.json`, `.txt`, etc. rather than the icon itself.

Answer (score 0):

**electron-v25.2.0**

Protocol can be used to avoid manual transfer.

```js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  protocol.handle("thum", async (request) => {
    let url = request.url.slice("thum:///".length);
    // The Windows implementation will ignore size.height and scale the height according to size.width.
    const image = await nativeImage.createThumbnailFromPath(url, {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
    });
    return new Response(image.toPNG(), {
      headers: { "content-type": "image/png" },
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<img src="thum:///D:\\a.jpg"
```

For me, getFileIcon is basically rubbish. I had to use extracticon.exe to extract the correct icon